# Editing INI-like files with a script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, configuration

I'm writing a script to automate setting up Puppet agent configuration files in Docker.

Basically, I need to ensure that the following section is in `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`:

```
[agent]
server=$PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME
masterport=$PUPPETMASTER_PORT
```

What I've been doing so far in my Puppet agent runit script is this:

```
function write_puppet_config () {
    read -d '' puppet_config <<EOF
[agent]
server=$1
masterport=$2
EOF

    echo -e "$puppet_config" >> /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
}

# default puppet master port is 8410
test -z "$PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_PORT" && export PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_PORT="8410"

# if there is a puppet master host defined, rewrite the config to match
if [ ! -z "$PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_HOST" ]; then 
    write_puppet_config "$PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_HOST" "$PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_PORT"
fi
```

The problem should be pretty apparent. If the Puppet configuration already specifies the configuration, I'm just appending another `[agent]` section, which is bad.

I could just switch on conditional logic (ie: grep if it's there and then rewrite it with sed if it is), but is there a way to do an edit from the command line? I'd like to basically run a command which says "if there isn't an agent section, add it, and then make sure that server and masterport are set to the right values in that section."

I know that structured tools like this exist for XML, but what about INI-style files?

Comment: Use Perl and https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::IniFiles

Comment: You should let puppet configure the puppet.conf. Just run with you master specified on the command line: `puppet agent -t --server yourmaster`.

Comment: @jordanm I'll probably actually end up doing that, but I'm still interested to see an actual solution for this.

Comment: @choroba, if you submitted that as an answer with a working example, I'd probably accept it as an answer.

Comment: Since your're already using Puppet, why not use Puppet for everything? [The inifile Puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/inifile) was made for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few script examples.  These are bare minimum and don't bother with
error checking, command line options, etc.  I've indicated whether I've run the script myself to verify its correctness.

### Ruby

Install the `inifile` rubygem for this script.  This script is **tested**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# filename: ~/config.rb

require 'inifile'

PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME='hello'
PUPPETMASTER_PORT='world'

ini = IniFile::load('/etc/puppet/puppet.conf')
ini['agent']['server'] = PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME
ini['agent']['masterport'] = PUPPETMASTER_PORT
ini.save
```

Usage:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/config.rb
$ sudo ~/config.rb     # or, if using rvm, rvmsudo ~/config.rb
```

### Perl

Install `Config::IniFiles` using `cpan` or your OS package manager (if there is
a package available).  This script is **untested** as I've stopped using `perl`
on my system.  It may need a little work, and corrections are welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# filename: ~/config.pl

use Config::IniFiles;

my $PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME='perl';
my $PUPPETMASTER_PORT='1234';

my $ini = Config::IniFiles->new(-file => '/etc/puppet/puppet.conf');

if (! $ini->SectionExists('agent')) {
    $ini->AddSection('agent');
}

if ($ini->exists('agent', 'server')) {
    $ini->setval('agent', 'server', $PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME);
}
else {
    $ini->newval('agent', 'server', $PUPPETMASTER_HOSTNAME);
}

if ($ini->exists('agent', 'masterport')) {
    $ini->setval('agent', 'masterport', $PUPPETMASTER_PORT);
}
else {
    $ini->newval('agent', 'masterport', $PUPPETMASTER_PORT);
}

$ini->RewriteConfig();
```

Usage:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/config.pl
$ sudo ~/config.pl
```

### awk

This script is more Bash and *nix friendly and uses a common utility of *nix OS's, `awk`.  This script is **tested**.

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
# filename: ~/config.awk

BEGIN {
    in_agent_section=0;
    is_host_done=0;
    is_port_done=0;
    host = "awk.com";
    port = "4567";
}

in_agent_section == 1 {
    if ($0 ~ /^server[[:space:]]*=/) {
        print "server="host;
        is_host_done = 1;
        next;
    }
    else if ($0 ~ /^masterport[[:space:]]*=/) {
        print "masterport="port;
        is_port_done = 1;
        next;
    }
    else if ($0 ~ /^\[/) {
        in_agent_section = 0;
        if (! is_host_done) {
            print "server="host;
        }
        if (! is_port_done) {
            print "masterport="port;
        }
    }
}

/^\[agent\]/ {
    in_agent_section=1;
}

{ print; }
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f ~/config.awk < /etc/puppet/puppet.conf > /tmp/puppet.conf
$ sudo mv /tmp/puppet.conf /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
```

Answer (score 26):

Have a look at [`crudini`](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programs/crudini/), which is a shell tool designed for this

```
conf=/etc/puppet/puppet.conf
crudini --set "$conf" agent server "$PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_HOST"
crudini --set "$conf" agent masterport "$PUPPET_MASTER_TCP_PORT"
```

or a single atomic invocation like:

```
echo "
[agent]
server=$1
masterport=$2" |

crudini --merge /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can afford to install external tools, than I would recommend Augeas - this is the only tool for working with config files you will ever need. It represents configs as a tree. Read more [here](http://augeas.net/index.html).

Comment: +1 for augeas. See https://peteris.rocks/blog/modifying-xml-json-ini-configuration-files-without-sed/