# Edit several lines from a certain section of an INI file

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have the subversion config file (`~/.subversion/servers`)

I need modify to add proxy information (host, port, exceptions). This file contains many sections with proxy information. I only want to modify **[global]**.

I have already created a regular expression for this but it does not work.

```
/(\[global\].*[\n])((.*[\n])*)([\s\#]*http-proxy-port\s?=\s?.*)/gm
```

You can try test online with https://regex101.com/ and it works great replacing with:

```
\1\2http-proxy-port=9000
```

I try with `sed` executing the line above and no word.

```
sed -i -r 's/(\[global].*[\n])((.*[\n])*)([\s\#]*http-proxy-port\s?=\s?.*)/\1\2http-proxy-port=9000/gm' \
 ~/.subversion/servers
```

How can I make `sed` work with the above regex ?

This sample subversion file:

```
### The currently defined server options are:
###   http-proxy-host            Proxy host for HTTP connection
###   http-proxy-port            Port number of proxy host service
###   http-proxy-username        Username for auth to proxy service
###   http-proxy-password        Password for auth to proxy service
###   http-proxy-exceptions      List of sites that do not use proxy
###   http-timeout               Timeout for HTTP requests in seconds

[groups]
# group1 = *.collab.net
# othergroup = repository.blarggitywhoomph.com
# thirdgroup = *.example.com

### Information for the first group:
# [group1]
# http-proxy-host = proxy1.some-domain-name.com
# http-proxy-port = 80
# http-proxy-username = blah
# http-proxy-password = doubleblah
# http-timeout = 60

### Information for the second group:
# [othergroup]
# http-proxy-host = proxy2.some-domain-name.com
# http-proxy-port = 9000

### SSL certificate.  See details above for overriding security
### due to SSL.
[global]
# http-proxy-exceptions = *.domain.org, *.domain.com
# http-proxy-host = proxy.domain.com
# http-proxy-port = 8080
# http-proxy-username = defaultusername
# http-proxy-password = defaultpassword
```

Expected output will be

```
...
[global]
http-proxy-exceptions = *.otherdomain.org, *.otherdomain.com, 127.0.0.1, localhost
http-proxy-host = proxy.otherdomain.com
http-proxy-port = 9000
# http-proxy-username = defaultusername
# http-proxy-password = defaultpassword
```

Comment: Expected out in post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, [there are better ways to edit INI files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137643)...
Still, here's one way with `sed`:

```
sed '/^\[.*\]/h
/http-proxy-exceptions/{x;/\[global\]/!{x;b;};x;c\
http-proxy-exceptions = *.otherdomain.org, *.otherdomain.com, 127.0.0.1, localhost
}
/http-proxy-host/{x;/\[global\]/!{x;b;};x;c\
http-proxy-host = proxy.otherdomain.com
}
/http-proxy-port/{x;/\[global\]/!{x;b;};x;c\
http-proxy-port = 9000
}' infile
```

This overwrites the hold buffer with the pattern space content each time it encounters an line matching `[.*]` (i.e. it saves each section name into the `h`old buffer). On  each line that matches your `http-.*` patterns it e`x`changes buffers - if the hold space does *not* (`!`) match `[global]` then it e`x`changes back and skips to next cycle via `b`. If the hold space matches `[global]` it e`x`changes back and `c`hanges the content of the pattern space.

Comment: I dont know how it works, but the script make the job. Thanks

Comment: You know how use to ignore no starting [.*]?

Comment: You know how use to ignore no starting [.*]?
Sample:

    [global]
    http-proxy-exceptions = .vtr.com,*.vtr.com,.vtr.cl,*.vtr.cl,127.0.0.1,localhost,::1,127.*,[::1]
    http-proxy-host = proxy.vtr.cl
    http-proxy-port = 8080
    # http-proxy-username = defaultusername

In this case sed no word because [::1] break the search

Comment: @ccolina - see edit - use `^` to anchor to beginning of line: `sed '/^\[.*\]/h...`